# Extracting div elements (Nokogiri/XPath/ruby)

Tags: html, css, ruby, xpath, nokogiri

I am trying to use nokogiri to scrape a page for some div text.

The pattern in the HTML looks like this. It has hundreds or divs so that are formatted this way:

```
<div class="thing text-text" data-thing-id="29966403">
  <div class="thinguser"><i class="ico ico-water ico-blue"></i>
  <div class="status">in 7 days
</div>
</div>
<div class="ignore-ui pull-right"><input type="check box" >
</div>
<div class="col_a col text">
  <div class="text">foobar
  </div>
  </div>
<div class="col_b col text">
  <div class="text">foobar desc
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

(sorry about the bad formatting)

I just want to grab the ID (data-thing-id) and the col_a text from each code block so that the output looks like:

```
29966403 foobar
29964234 barfoo
```

Here's the code I currently have that does not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

tids = Array.new
terms = Array.new

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("http://somewebsite.com/"))

tids = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'thing')]/data-thing-id()").collect {|node| node.text.strip}
terms = doc.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'col_b')]/text()").collect {|node| node.text.strip}

tids.zip(terms).each do |tid.term|
puts tid+" "+term
end
```

Thanks in advance,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tids =  doc.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' thing ')]").collect {|node| node['data-thing-id']}
terms = doc.xpath("//div[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '),' col_b ')]").collect {|node| node.text.strip }

tids.zip(terms).each do |tid, term|
  puts tid+" "+term
end
#  => 29966403 foobar desc
```

What the above code is doing is using an XPATH on the doc to find each of the [DIVs that contain the classes](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/XPath%3a%20Select%20element%20by%20class.htm) `thing` and `col_b` respectively. Then it takes each of the found DIVs and extracts either the attribute `data-thing-id` or the displayed text contained within the element, and creates arrays out of the results.

Nokogiri supports both [`xpath`](http://www.w3schools.com/XPath/) and [`css`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/), and you can find how to fully utilize those tools by looking at their respective documentations

Comment: Would anyone be kind enough to explain in detail what the tids and terms assignment lines are doing?  I am trying to extract status data from <div class="status">in 7 days</div> and can't seem to do it. Also, I have been reading Nokogiri documentation and I do not see anything in the examples that apply to this.  Should I be reading xpath documentation instead?

Comment: @user1117603 I've added an explanation. The short answer is - yes, you should be reading xpath documentation.